# cakephp Auth or Acl to manage my web application

Tags: authentication, cakephp, acl

hey 
I'm new in cake and now I initial build my first project 
and succesful to use Auth component and next step 
I want to make permission group and I read Acl in book.cakephp and 
I confused in it . and I try to search other way  I found
 the auth component It can be done and I have question in future
if my project have many feature and table 
Auth or Acl thing that can manage it better.

I will have to study the instructions and use

sorry to my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AuthComponent is used to verify and manage a user's connection to your application.  If you only have one type of user in your system, you only would need to use AuthComponent.

ACL is used to manage whether or not an authenticated user can access a given object/action in the system.  ACL requires AuthComponent (or another verification and session management tool) to first verify who the user actually is.  In other words, if you need ACL, you need AuthComponent too.

Comment: if you are not sure, you probably don't need acl. its a complex beast and is hardly ever needed.

Comment: k dogmatic69 I found [link]http://www.studiocanaria.com/articles/cakephp_auth_component_users_groups_permissions_revisited[link] it write since I don't know php but I doubt when my web is many table and feature . Auth or Acl to  build it which is easier to manage it